# How to add new div at the bottom of product details page using catalog_product_view.xml in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product

I want to show my custom block at bottom of product details page (after tab section) in Magento 2.3. How can I do this?

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Vendor\CatalogProduct\Block\Custom" name="custom" template="Vendor_CatalogProduct::product/view/custom.phtml" after="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Does your template show?

Comment: can you update full code of your catalog_product_view.xml and its path?

Comment: what's the full path of "custom.phtml" within your module

Comment: @PhilippSander app/code/Vendor/CatalogProduct/view/frontend/templates/product/view/custom_insta.phtml

Comment: @SebastianT
Yes, Only issue with the block position

Comment: You can try to to use after="name.of.last.element" instead of after="-". Sometimes few elements can have set after="-".

Comment: @SebastianT
After upsell product section in product details page.

Comment: what's the full file path of the XML? did you enable your module and have you cleaned the cache?

Comment: @PhilippSander
app/design/frontend/Alothemes/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Comment: No i see that "product.info.upsell" is in containre "content.aside", so please try:   <referenceContainer name="content.aside"> instead of <referenceContainer name="content">.

Comment: and after="product.info.upsell"

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have used the move tag for moving my custom block after content bottom

```
<move element="custom" destination="main" after="content.bottom"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

add Below in your custom `catalog_product_view.xml` layout file.

> app/design/frontend/ThemeVendor/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Your\Block\Class" name="custom.block" after="product.info.details" template="Vendor_Module::product/test.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
```